# Not able to repartition the DStream

Tags: spark-streaming, apache-spark-2.0

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("yarn-cluster")
                               .setAppName("SparkJob")
                               .set("spark.executor.memory","2G")
                               .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout","5")

val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Minutes(1))

var historyRdd: RDD[(String, ArrayList[String])] = streamingContext.sparkContext.emptyRDD

var historyRdd_2: RDD[(String, ArrayList[String])] = streamingContext.sparkContext.emptyRDD

val stream_1 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, GenericData.Record, StringDecoder, GenericDataRecordDecoder](streamingContext, kafkaParams ,  Set(inputTopic_1))
val dstream_2 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, GenericData.Record, StringDecoder, GenericDataRecordDecoder](streamingContext, kafkaParams ,  Set(inputTopic_2))

val dstream_2 = stream_2.map((r: Tuple2[String, GenericData.Record]) => 
{
    //some mapping
}

dstream_1.foreachRDD(r => r.repartition(500))
val historyDStream = dstream_1.transform(rdd => rdd.union(historyRdd))
dstream_2.foreachRDD(r => r.repartition(500))
val historyDStream_2 = dstream_2.transform(rdd => rdd.union(historyRdd_2))
val fullJoinResult = historyDStream.fullOuterJoin(historyDStream_2)

val filtered = fullJoinResult.filter(r => r._2._1.isEmpty)


filtered.foreachRDD{rdd =>
    val formatted = rdd.map(r  => (r._1 , r._2._2.get)) 
    historyRdd_2.unpersist(false) // unpersist the 'old' history RDD
    historyRdd_2 = formatted // assign the new history
    historyRdd_2.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK) // cache the computation
}

val filteredStream = fullJoinResult.filter(r => r._2._2.isEmpty)

filteredStream.foreachRDD{rdd =>
    val formatted = rdd.map(r => (r._1 , r._2._1.get)) 
    historyRdd.unpersist(false) // unpersist the 'old' history RDD
    historyRdd = formatted // assign the new history
    historyRdd.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK) // cache the computation
}

streamingContext.start()
streamingContext.awaitTermination()
}
}
```

I am not able to repartition the DStream using the above code , I was getting 128 partitions for my input which is the no. of Kafka partitons , and because of Join I need to shuffle read and write data so I wanted to increase the parallelism by increasing no- of partitions. But the partitions remains the same.Why is it so? 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like `map` or `filter`, `repartition` is a transformation in Spark, meaning 3 things:

- it returns another immutable RDD
- it's lazy
- it needs to be materialized by some action

Considering this code:

```
dstream_1.foreachRDD(r => r.repartition(500))
```

Using `repartition` as a side-effect within a `foreachRDD` does nothing. The resulting `RDD` is never used and therefore the repartitioning never takes place.

We should 'chain' this transformation with the other operations in the job. In this context, a simple way to achieve this would be to use `transform` instead:

```
val repartitionedDStream = dstream_1.transform(rdd => rdd.repartition(500))
... use repartitionedDStream further on ...
```

Comment: How can I minimize the shuffle? Before join there are 131 partitionsfor union dstream (128 of dstream + 3 of history) , and after join there are 3 partitions  , what can I do to tune my application. Also repartitioning increased then processing time without making difference in shuffling

Comment: @massg why there is shuffling at the stage performing the union task.

Comment: @JSR29 The shuffle is triggered by the `join`. The union is just the stage that leads to that shuffle. This explanation is quite good:http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.spark.user/4887

Comment: There is shuffle read in both stages of union for producing historyDstream_1 and historyDStream_2.I infered this from stages in web UI , as my job is divided in three stages a)Union(historyDStream_1) , b)Union(historyDStream_2)      c)Join

Comment: It seems you can have a union-triggered shuffle if the partitioners are not equal. Worth checking in this case.

Comment: I tried to repartition the history RDD so that it will have same number of partitions as the input dstream , but that repartition took place in first iteration only, Why?